# how to show all attributes even filters applied in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

how to show all attributes even filters applied i.e., if we click on like color options then some options get's cleared so i want to display all filters whether if we choose another option also.

Answer (score 0):

You can show color attribute even if there is no products available related to this. You have to select **Filterable (no results)** in attribute's storefront properties.

Navigate to

> Stores > Attributes > Product > Color > Storefront Properties > Used
>   in layered navigation

and select **Filterable (no results)**.

Comment: Hi @dinesh, yes it is working but there are all options which have no results also so  I want with results.

Answer (score 0):

To show all attributes even filters applied in magento 2.Please check below solution.

1. Have to set Filterable (No results) For that Attribute:

> Store > Attribute > Product > {Your Attribute} >StoreFront Properties > Used in layered Navigation

select Filterable (no results).

2. Checked Category Selected as **Anchor**.
3. **Coding changes** to display all attribute.

   We have to override `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute` File. So Use this link https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/ To override Model in Magento 2.After Override of this model complete do below changes in **Attribute.php** file of your.

   - Have to change in apply() Function of Attribute.php file.
   - Please check `$this->setItems([])` in apply() function and replace this line by this `if($productCollection->getValueSearchRequestName() != "catalog_view_container"){
         $this->setItems([]); // set items to disable show filtering
     }`
4. Do DI compile,Flush cache,Deploy Static content and remove files from generated folder then check it.

   - php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   - php bin/magento cache:flush
   - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   - rm -rf generated/*

Thank you